# android, andengine, pureMVC framework integration

Tags: android, model-view-controller, andengine, puremvc

I want to use pureMVC framework for my android application.

I also want to use Android andengine in this application.

How can I integrate them? Is there any way to do that? If yes, can you send me link on some tutorials or sample, or template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it compulsory to use PureMVC?

Yesterday I've [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519163/comments-on-my-mvp-pattern-for-android/7609943#7609943) similar question about MVC architecture on Android.

Don't reinvent the wheel, Android SDK offers excellent MVC/MVP/MVVM architecture for you.

Comment: It's not reinventing the wheel, what puremvc ecosystem has, no other framework can provide, not even what comes with android, I am talking about multicore puremvc systems, connected via unix style pipes, state machine, async macro commands and proxies, the holy grail of computing.